# C# Leave Method from within Lambda delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I am new to lambda and delegates but I want to rewrite some existing methods for simplicity.

Background: There is a Client and a Server Application which will communicate via Sockets. **CommunicationMessage** is a class which will hold the values to send / received.

I defined a method with Actions as parameters.

```
public void SendAndReceive(CommunicationMessage query, Action<CommunicationMessage> OnReceivedResponse, Action<int> OnReceivedError, Action OnFailedSending) { ... }
```

This Method will be called like this:

```
public static void LoginUser(string email, string password)
    {
        // Create the query which will be sent to the Server
        CommunicationMessage query = MessageContentGenerator.GenerateLoginQuery(email, password).Result;

        // Perorm the sending operation
        CommunicationController.SendAndReceive(query,
            (response) =>
            {
                BaseUser user = BaseUserController.Parse(response);
                ...
            },
            (errorCode) =>
            {
                // From here I want to leave the method LoginUser()
            },
            () =>
            {
            }
        );
    }
```

As you can see I want to leave the Method from within that Lambda delegate. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define another method returning `Task<CommunicationMessage>` to obtain response (this is like a core method), next you define another returning `Task<BaseUser>` based on that core method. All can be done using `TaskCompletionSource`, like this:

```
public Task<CommunicationMessage> SendAsync(CommunicationMessage query, Action<int> OnReceivedError, Action OnFailedSending) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CommunicationMessage>();
    SendAndReceiveAsync(query, cm => tcs.TrySetResult(cm), OnReceivedError, OnFailedSending);
    return tcs.Task;
}
//for BaseUser result
public static async Task<BaseUser> LoginUserAsync(string email, string password)
{
    // Create the query which will be sent to the Server
    var query = MessageContentGenerator.GenerateLoginQuery(email, password).Result;
    var result = await SendAsync(query, (errorCode) => {}, () => {});
    return BaseUserController.Parse(result);
}
```

You can find more about `TaskCompletionSource` to take its benefit to turn tradition async methods (with callbacks) into awaitable methods which can be used with await. It even can handle error and raise exception so that you can use `try-catch` seamlessly (no need to use error callback).

Comment: Yes I do it like this normally but I want to go away from this type of implementation and focus more on Design patterns. I edited the topic a little to clear things.

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin still I do not understand what your problem is (confused with what you commented here). In fact with the method `SendAndReceiveAsync` designed like what you have it now, the solution I provided here is very well-known and should be followed as a good practice (to take benefit of using async/await). If you can change the design of `SendAndReceiveAsync`, then just go ahead with it right away to support async and await with `Task<T>` instead of just `Task`. Then you don't need any extra method to convert between the patterns

Comment: There is no need to use async for this method, this was just an example. So I edited it again. I want to leave (return) the whole method * LoginUser* from within the second lambda. Hope this helps to understand what I mean

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin there is no way to return from right in the passed-in callback. The execution flow when at the end of the callback will continue your `SendAndReceive` method, at the end of that method, it will continue your `LoginUser`. So if you want to control execution flow, your method `SendAndReceive` should return some result, based on this you can determine the execution flow. Also your callback should possibly  return some result, so that your `SendAndReceive` method can determine when it should return immediately.

Comment: Okay thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. So for simplicity I should declare **bool worked** and after the SendAndReceive I should check it's value. Thank you for your help!